Intuition behind proof that the set of all closed points of $\text{Spec}(A)$ is dense, for finitely generated $k$-algebras $A$
I recently read a proof (linked below) that the closed points of $\text{Spec}(A)$ are dense. I understand the proof, but I think I'm not practiced enough with commutative algebra to have come up with it myself. My intuition for this problem comes from considering polynomials in $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Nonzero polynomials should not be contained in every maximal ideal, as this would imply that they go to zero on all of $\mathbb{C}$. But this doesn't seem to be the idea behind the linked proof. Am I thinking about this the right way? I would really like to understand this.
The proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1611485/1338624

Your idea is somehow encapsulated in that proof. Saying that $f$ cannot vanish on the whole of $\mathbb{C}$ corresponds to the fact that localization $A_f$ is nonzero, so has a maximal ideal. In your example, the closed points or maximal ideals take a very simple form, but if you allow more variables then we need Nullstellensatz to describe them. Allowing further $k\ne \bar{k}$ results in one more algebraic step.

It is a good idea to understand geometrically what is hapenning. Your example is a good one ; we interpret the belonging to a prime ideal as some cancellation over some curves / points in the case of maximal ideals. 
We may want to say that a non zero polynomial is not zero everywhere, thus must not vanish on some closed points. Unfortunately, the first statement is not true. For example, over a finite field, a non zero polynomial can vanish everywhere, but it will always be nonvanishing over some finite extension. This idea may lead to a proof, as closed points of a finite algebra are more than just ideals $(X_1-a_1,\dots,X_n-a_n)$. They contain the finite extensions of $k$. Here is a way of thinking ; 

If $k=\bar{k}$, let $f\in A$, by the Nullstellensatz, if $f$ is zero on every maximal ideal of $\textrm{Spec}(A)$, then $f\in \sqrt{0}$, then $D(f)=\emptyset$. Thus the result. 
We may ponder a bit and conclude that this is in fact the proof in the answer you link. Indeed, a standard proof of the Nullstellensatz uses that a domain which is a fnite vector space is a field extension. 

When $k$ is not algebraically closed, we change the basis. Consider the injection $A\rightarrow A\otimes_k \bar{k}$, which leads to the map over the spectra $$\textrm{Spec}(A\otimes_k \bar{k}) \rightarrow \textrm{Spec}(A).$$
In general, if $B$ and $C$ are rings over some other ring $R$, we have $$\textrm{Spec}(B\otimes_R C) = \textrm{Spec}(B) \times_{\textrm{Spec}(R)} \textrm{Spec}(C),$$ and primes above a pair $(\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q})$ are the prime ideals of $\kappa(\mathfrak{p}) \otimes_R \kappa(\mathfrak{q})$. This might seem weird, but tensor product of fields or of intergral domains are not fields/integral domains. They can split, for example, if $\ell|k$ is finite Galois of group $G$, then the Chinese remainder theorem gives an isomorphism $$\ell\otimes_k \ell \rightarrow \bigoplus_{\sigma\in G} \ell.$$

Anyway, let us come back to our algebras. The ring map $A\rightarrow A\otimes_k \bar{k}$ is injective, thus the spectrum map $\textrm{Spec}(A\otimes_k \bar{k}) \rightarrow \textrm{Spec}(A)$ has dense image. In particular, it maps dense sets to dense sets. From the correspondence between primes of a tensor product and pairs of primes, we see that this mapping maps closed points of $\textrm{Spec}(A\otimes_k \bar{k})$ to closed points of $\textrm{Spec}(A)$. We know from the algebraically closed case that closed points of $\textrm{Spec}(A\otimes_k \bar{k})$ are dense, we conclude that closed points of $\textrm{Spec}(A)$ are dense.

The first of probably several questions: you said a nonzero polynomial over a finite field can vanish everywhere. But how can this be? Such a polynomial ring has zero Jacobson radical.

I made a small error of terminology in this sentence. By vanishing everywhere, I meant everywhere on $k^n$ ; If $k$ is finite, take $f=\prod_{i=1}^n \prod_{x\in k} (X_i - x)$, which vanishes on $k^n$. But as you mention, the "function" $f$ taking a prime $\mathfrak{p}$, and sending it to $f \ \textrm{mod} \ \mathfrak{p}$ is not zero ; You can prove this directly by proving that $f$ is not zero over $\ell^n$, for some finite extension $\ell | k$.
